# c# web browser click on a button with a class name

Tags: c#

I need help on clicking a button with a class name.
I want to click this button bellow.

```
<a href="https://www.supremenewyork.com/checkout" class="button checkout">checkout now</a>
```

I tried this but the button does not click.

```
HtmlElementCollection classButton = webBrowser1.Document.All;
            foreach (HtmlElement element in classButton)
            {
                if (element.GetAttribute("button checkout") == "button")
                {
                    element.InvokeMember("click");
                }
            }
```

Comment: You're probably supposed to get the `"class"` attribute

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for an attribute called "button checkout" instead of class. You should probably use .Contains as well so if there are several classes then it doesn't miss them:

```
HtmlElementCollection classButton = webBrowser1.Document.All;
foreach (HtmlElement element in classButton)
{
    if (element.GetAttribute("class").Contains("button"))
    {
        element.InvokeMember("click");
    }
}
```

If you want to make sure you are finding "button" and not something like "redbutton" then change to this:

```
HtmlElementCollection classButton = webBrowser1.Document.All;
foreach (HtmlElement element in classButton)
{
    if (Regex.IsMatch(element.GetAttribute("class"), @"\bbutton\b"))
    {
        element.InvokeMember("click");
    }
}
```

You could maybe streamline using LINQ as well:

```
webBrowser1.Document.All.Where(
     element => element.GetAttribute("class").Contains("button"))/*OR regex in example 2*/
    .ToList().ForEach(element => element.InvokeMember("click"))
```