# How do i programmatically click a button with C# in IE by classname?

Tags: c#, html

So i'm trying to create a code which will automatically click buttons for me in my `webBroswer1` object in my visual studio C# Windows form application.

However, the buttons in the website i would want to click do not have IDs, therefore it'd need to be my href/classname

The tag of the buttons is `<a>`and the href is `javascript:void(0)`, could someone assist me please?

Comment: This page might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33439447/c-sharp-web-browser-click-on-a-button-with-a-class-name

Answer (score 0):

The answer found here might help you: [c# web browser click on a button with a class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33439447/c-sharp-web-browser-click-on-a-button-with-a-class-name)

Here is an example:

```
HtmlElementCollection classButton = webBrowser1.Document.All;
foreach (HtmlElement element in classButton)
{
if (element.GetAttribute("class").Contains("button"))
{
    element.InvokeMember("click");
}
}
```